# How to get all inputs from a form - not working from selector

Tags: jquery

I have the following html:

              
                  
                      
                        
                        
                          ×

```
                    <!-- Modal Body -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <form id="modal_revenue_form" role="form" method="POST" action="">
                        <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_year" class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_year">Year</label>
                            <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" id="modal_revenue_form_year" data-placeholder="Select a year">
                              <option value="" ></option>
                                                                <option value="2015" >
                                2015
                              </option>
                                                                <option value="2016" >
                                2016
                              </option>
                                                                <option value="2017" >
                                2017
                              </option>
                                                                <option value="2018" >
                                2018
                              </option>
                                                                <option value="2019" >
                                2019
                              </option>
                                                                <option value="2020"  selected >
                                2020
                              </option>
                                                                <option value="2021" >
                                2021
                              </option>
                                                                <option value="2022" >
                                2022
                              </option>
                                                                <option value="2023" >
                                2023
                              </option>
                                                                <option value="2024" >
                                2024
                              </option>
                                                                <option value="2025" >
                                2025
                              </option>
                                                              </select>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_year_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_fpc" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_fpc">FPC</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_fpc" class="form-control" placeholder="FPC"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_fpc_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                                                    <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_jan" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_jan">jan</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_jan" class="form-control" placeholder="jan"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_jan_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                                                    <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_feb" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_feb">feb</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_feb" class="form-control" placeholder="feb"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_feb_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                                                    <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_mar" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_mar">mar</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_mar" class="form-control" placeholder="mar"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_mar_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                                                    <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_apr" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_apr">apr</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_apr" class="form-control" placeholder="apr"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_apr_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                                                    <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_may" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_may">may</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_may" class="form-control" placeholder="may"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_may_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                                                    <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_jun" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_jun">jun</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_jun" class="form-control" placeholder="jun"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_jun_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                                                    <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_jul" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_jul">jul</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_jul" class="form-control" placeholder="jul"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_jul_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                                                    <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_aug" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_aug">aug</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_aug" class="form-control" placeholder="aug"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_aug_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                                                    <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_sep" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_sep">sep</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_sep" class="form-control" placeholder="sep"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_sep_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                                                    <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_oct" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_oct">oct</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_oct" class="form-control" placeholder="oct"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_oct_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                                                    <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_nov" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_nov">nov</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_nov" class="form-control" placeholder="nov"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_nov_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                                                    <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_dec" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_dec">dec</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_dec" class="form-control" placeholder="dec"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_dec_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div id="modal_revenue_form_hidden"></div>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal Footer -->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" id="modal_revenue_create_update_button" class="btn btn-success"></button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Modal -->
```

and the following jquery to set all inputs to a certain value:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function modal_revenue_form_clean(title) {
          $('#modal_revenue_title').text(title+' Revenue');
          $('#modal_revenue_create_update_button').text(title);
          $('#modal_revenue_form_hidden').empty();

          // Set date to today's year
          var d = new Date();
          var year = d.getFullYear()
          $('select#modal_revenue_form_year').val(year);
          $('select#modal_revenue_form_year').select2().trigger('change');

          $('#modal_revenue_form_fpc').val(0);

          // Clean all input <---- I don't get this alert below
          $("form#modal_revenue_form input").each(function(){
            alert('ok');
            $(this).val('dfgsdfgdf');
          });
          // Set all months value to 0
          @foreach(config('select.available_months') as $key => $month)
            $('#modal_revenue_form_{{ $month }}').val(0);
          @endforeach

          //modal_revenue_form_error_clean();
        }
});
```

This jquery code is in a function and when I call it, nothing happens, I don't get alerts. I ave checked on other website and it seems this is the way to select all inputs in a specific form.

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

You need wrap your code inside document ready as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("form#modal_revenue_form input").each(function(){
        //alert('ok');
        $(this).val('dfgsdfgdf');
      });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("form#modal_revenue_form input").each(function(){
        //alert('ok');
        $(this).val('dfgsdfgdf');
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
!-- Modal Body -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <form id="modal_revenue_form" role="form" method="POST" action="">
                        <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_year" class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_year">Year</label>
                            <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" id="modal_revenue_form_year" data-placeholder="Select a year">
                              <option value="" ></option>
                                                                <option value="2015" >
                                2015
                              </option>
                                                                <option value="2016" >
                                2016
                              </option>
                                                                <option value="2017" >
                                2017
                              </option>
                                                                <option value="2018" >
                                2018
                              </option>
                                                                <option value="2019" >
                                2019
                              </option>
                                                                <option value="2020"  selected >
                                2020
                              </option>
                                                                <option value="2021" >
                                2021
                              </option>
                                                                <option value="2022" >
                                2022
                              </option>
                                                                <option value="2023" >
                                2023
                              </option>
                                                                <option value="2024" >
                                2024
                              </option>
                                                                <option value="2025" >
                                2025
                              </option>
                                                              </select>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_year_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_fpc" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_fpc">FPC</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_fpc" class="form-control" placeholder="FPC"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_fpc_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                                                    <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_jan" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_jan">jan</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_jan" class="form-control" placeholder="jan"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_jan_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                                                    <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_feb" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_feb">feb</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_feb" class="form-control" placeholder="feb"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_feb_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                                                    <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_mar" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_mar">mar</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_mar" class="form-control" placeholder="mar"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_mar_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                                                    <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_apr" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_apr">apr</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_apr" class="form-control" placeholder="apr"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_apr_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                                                    <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_may" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_may">may</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_may" class="form-control" placeholder="may"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_may_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                                                    <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_jun" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_jun">jun</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_jun" class="form-control" placeholder="jun"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_jun_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                                                    <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_jul" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_jul">jul</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_jul" class="form-control" placeholder="jul"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_jul_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                                                    <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_aug" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_aug">aug</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_aug" class="form-control" placeholder="aug"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_aug_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                                                    <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_sep" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_sep">sep</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_sep" class="form-control" placeholder="sep"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_sep_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                                                    <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_oct" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_oct">oct</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_oct" class="form-control" placeholder="oct"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_oct_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                                                    <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_nov" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_nov">nov</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_nov" class="form-control" placeholder="nov"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_nov_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                                                    <div id="modal_revenue_formgroup_dec" class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label" for="modal_revenue_form_dec">dec</label>
                            <input type="text" id="modal_revenue_form_dec" class="form-control" placeholder="dec"></input>
                            <span id="modal_revenue_form_dec_error" class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div id="modal_revenue_form_hidden"></div>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal Footer -->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" id="modal_revenue_create_update_button" class="btn btn-success"></button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Modal -->
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that it is wrapped already in it... I will edit my post

Comment: did you wrap it content use bootstrap modal?

Comment: yes, I m using bootstrap 3 but why would it make anything different, jquery should only go through each input in my form, no?